# SQL random aggregate

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Say I have a simple table with 3 fields: 'place', 'user' and 'bytes'. Let's say, that under some filter, I want to group by 'place', and for each 'place', to sum all the bytes for that place, and randomly select a user for that place (uniformly from all the users that fit the 'where' filter and the relevant 'place'). If there was a "select randomly from" aggregate function, I would do:

```
SELECT place, SUM(bytes), SELECT_AT_RANDOM(user) WHERE .... GROUP BY place;
```

...but I couldn't find such an aggregate function. Am I missing something? What could be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any individual RDBMS with such a function.  Most need to use some other mechanism to achieve the same result *(Such as assigning a random number to each user, then picking the user with the highest value.)*  But each will have different capabilities, and each will perform differently.  So, this really is an RDBMS specific question.

Comment: If you are using MySQL just write an incorrect `GROUP BY` (e.g. do not apply an aggregate on user) and it will choose a row by random.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It won't be a uniformly random user, though.

Answer (score 5):

If your RDBMS supports analytical functions.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT place,
                Sum(bytes) OVER (PARTITION BY place) AS Sum_bytes,
                user,
                Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY place ORDER BY random_function()) AS RN
         FROM   YourTable
         WHERE  .... )
SELECT place,
       Sum_bytes,
       user
FROM   T
WHERE  RN = 1;
```

For SQL Server `Crypt_gen_random(4)` or `NEWID()` would be examples of something that could be substituted in for `random_function()`

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is DBMS specific. If your DBMS is MySql, you can use a solution like this:

```
SELECT place_rand.place, SUM(place_rand.bytes), place_rand.user as random_user
FROM
  (SELECT place, bytes, user
   FROM place
   WHERE ...
   ORDER BY rand()) place_rand
GROUP BY
  place_rand.place;
```

The subquery orders records in random order. The outer query groups by `place`, sums `bytes`, and returns first random user, since user is not in an aggregate function and neither in the group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

With a custom aggregate function, you could write expressions as simple as:

```
SELECT place, SUM(bytes), SELECT_AT_RANDOM(user) WHERE .... GROUP BY place;
```

`SELECT_AT_RAMDOM` would be the custom aggregate function.

Here is precisely [an implementation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Random) in **PostgreSQL**.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a bit of a variation on Martin's solution:

```
select place, sum(bytes), max(case when seqnum = 1 then user end) as random_user
from (select place, bytes,
             row_number() over (partition by place order by newid()) as sequm
       from t
      ) t
group by place
```

(Where newid() is just one way to get a random number, depending on the database.)

For some reason, I prefer this approach, because it still has the aggregation function in the outer query.  If you are summarizing a bunch of fields, then this seems cleaner to me.